# How can I change multiple Checkboxes in React Hook Form Via state

Tags: reactjs, forms, checkbox, react-hook-form

Oky, so wasted like 12 hours already on this. And I really need help.

I created a filter using an array via Map that returns some checkbox components

**Component:**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

interface Checkbox {
    id: string | undefined,
    name: string,
    reg: any,
    value: any,
    label: string,
    required?: boolean,
    allChecked: boolean
}



const Checkbox = ({ id, name, reg, value, label, allChecked }: Checkbox) => {

    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setChecked(allChecked);
    }, [allChecked])


    return (
        <>
            <label key={id}>

                <input type="checkbox"
                    {...reg}
                    id={id}
                    value={value}
                    name={name}
                    checked={checked}
                    onClick={() => {
                        setChecked(!checked)
                    }}
                    onChange={
                        () => { }
                    }
                />

                {label}

            </label>
        </>
    )
}

export default Checkbox;
```

**Map:**

```
                                    dataValues.sort()
                                        ?
                                        dataValues.map((e: any, i: number) => {

                                            let slug = e.replace(' ', '-').toLowerCase();
                                            return (
                                                <div key={JSON.stringify(e)} id={JSON.stringify(e)}
                                                >
                                                    <Checkbox id={slug}

                                                        name={title as string}
                                                        label={e as string}
                                                        value={e}
                                                        reg={{ ...register(title as string) }}
                                                        allChecked={allChecked}

                                                    />
                                                </div>
                                            )
                                        })
                                        :
                                        null
                                }
```

**State that is just above the Map:**

```
const [allChecked, setAllChecked] = useState<boolean>(false);
```

When I try to change the state on the parent and check or uncheck all of the checkboxes, nothing happens.

(the form works without a problem if I manually click on the checkboxes, but I cannot do this as I have some sections with over 40 values)

Sample of array:

```
dataValues = [
    "Blugi",
    "Bluza",
    "Body",
    "Bratara",
    "Camasa",
    "Cardigan",
    "Ceas",
    "Cercel",
    "Colier",
    "Fusta",
    "Geanta Cross-body",
    "Hanorac",
    "Jacheta",
    "Palton",
    "Pantaloni",
    "Pulover",
    "Rochie",
    "Rucsac",
    "Sacou",
    "Salopeta",
    "Set-Accesorii",
    "Top",
    "Trench",
    "Tricou",
    "Vesta"
]
```

Comment: Console.log in the useEffect, does it run?

Comment: Yes, the useEffect for allChecked runs for all of the checkboxes and I get false or true.

Answer (score 0):

`allChecked` never changes (at least in the code shown here).

Here's the timeline:

1. The parent passes down a boolean prop `allChecked`. That's supposed to tell us if all the checkboxes are checked or not.
2. `useEffect` in `Checkbox` runs on mount, and `allChecked` is `false` because that's its default. `useEffect` then sets `checked` to `allChecked`'s value, `false`. Which it already is, because its default is also `false`.
3. `useEffect` then listens for a change in `allChecked` via `[allChecked]` that never comes.
4. Clicking on any checkbox just toggles the state of that checkbox. `allChecked`'s setter, `setAllChecked`, is never passed to the child or called from the parent.

#### What's the solution?

Somewhere, `setAllChecked(true)` needs to happen. Maybe a single checkbox with a label "Check all"?

Then, `allChecked` in `Checkbox` needs to be able to control the checkbox inputs. One implementation could be:

```
checked={checked || allChecked}
```

Comment: I managed to fix this visually by setting the main state values to null. (so you can go to false or true after that). Thanks for the headsUp. 
 
  const [allChecked, setAllChecked] = useState<boolean | null>(null);

 const [checked, setChecked] = useState<boolean | null>(null);
checked={checked || allChecked || false}
The checkboxes visually update, yet, when I submit, the form will only see the checkboxes that were clicked manually, by hand. And not the ones that updated via setAllChecked

Comment: Yet, 

What happens if I click a couple. I press Clear all and set AllChecked = false. 

Press a couple again, clear all doesn't work the second time, cause the state was updated to false before and can't do it again.

Comment: I think that allowing boolean values to be null makes this problem harder.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this.

There were 2 main problems:

1. Checkboxes were not rendering again so react-hook-form would see the old value, no matter what
2. I couldn't press clear all multiple times, because I was sending the allChecked = = false info multiple times, and the state wasn't exactly changing.

What I did was force a render by integrating the allChecked state as an object

interface checkedState {
checked: boolean,
render: boolean
}

So, whenever I send the state, I send it something like:

```
{ 
checked: true, 
render: !allChecked.render 
}
```

meaning that the new object is always new, no matter if I send the same information.